# Are my contacts encrypted on my Android?

Tags: contacts, privacy, encryption

Are my contacts encrypted on my Android and where are they?

How can I access them? Any public APIs? (From PC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least honeycomb allows user to encrypt all data (see article on http://www.netbooklive.com/android-honeycomb-can-encrypt-all-your-data-7497/).

You can export all your contacts from the application (tap in contacts app on menu, then import/export and choose export to SD Card)

Comment: By _access_, I mean from PC.

Comment: updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but an additional: if I do not export it to SD, where they originally are? Can I see them from PC?

Comment: You can see your contacts saved in google account in Google contacts. Contacts on the phone are stored at /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts.db